# How to Set an Expiration Date after a Year in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to make an investment website where I want to set an expiration date exactly after a year that the registration was made. Upon the registration, an initial deposit is required which is the one with the value "500" which is fixed on every registration. I want to use the `created_at` timestamp from my database table `money_trade_deposits` as the reference for the start date and calculate the expiration date based on that after a year and pass it on my laravel blade view. I'm new to laravel and I have no idea how to this.

This is my `money_trade_deposits` table and I wanna base the expiration date from the `created_at` date.
[image]

Or it it possible to add a new timestamp row which will automatically calculate the expiration date adter a year? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might consider an accessor function to handle this automatically.

Comment: For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor 
 Something like `public function getExpiresAtAttribute(){ return $this->created_at->addYear(); }`, then accessed via `$model->expires_at;`

Comment: So I'm gonna add that to my model right? Where do I call this query `$model->expires_at; `? Sorry I'm still quite confused with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `created_at` is automatically casted as a `Carbon` instance in Laravel, you can calculate the expiration date one year after with the `->addYear()` method.
Ex: `$model->created_at->addYear()->toDateTimeString()`.
Reference: [Carbon doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: please mark as resolved if this has solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must use Carbon here to add a year from the day of the initial deposit.
Laravel automatically wraps up created_at to Carbon instance, and Carbon instance you can easily add year using addYear() function. See Documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs.

I will suggest you to create a new column for expiration date and set it initially rather than adding a year to created_at each time to check expiration. Anyway, Carbon is very useful for this type of date processings.